The total space of the direct sum of Mobius band and trivial vector bundle
We can consider the open Mobius band $M$ as a real line bundle over $S^1$, and it is nonorientable as a vector bundle. Let $E_n$ denote the trivial real rank $n$ vector bundle over $S^1$. Then is the direct sum $E_n\oplus M$ nonorientable?
I'm curious about a way showing this without using Stiefel-Whitney classes. For example if we know the total space of $E_n\oplus M$ we can compare it with the trivial bundle $E_{n+1}=S^1\times \Bbb R^{n+1}$.
Also, can the sum of a nonorientable bundle and an orientable bundle be orientable?

"can the sum of a nonorientable bundle and an orientable bundle be orientable?" No, since its first SW-class does not vanish.

The answer to "can the sum of a nonorientable bundle and an orientable bundle be orientable" is no: A vector bundle $E$ is orientable iff $\omega_1(E) = 0$, so if $E$ is orientable and $E'$ is not, you obtain from the product formula that
$$
    \omega_1(E \oplus E') = \omega_1(E) \omega_0(E') + \omega_0(E) \omega_1(E') = \omega_1(E') \neq 0
$$
whence $E \oplus E'$ is not orientable.
For your specific example, one can avoid the use of characteristic classes and argue as follows: Orientability of $E_n \oplus M$ is equivalent to the existence of a Thom isomorphism $\newcommand{\Th}{\operatorname{Th}}\Phi\colon H^*(S^1; \mathbb{Z}) \overset{\cong}{\to} H^{n + 1}(\Th(E_n \oplus M); \mathbb{Z})$. However, $\Th(M) \cong \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2$ and $\Th$ turns trivial summands into suspensions, which means that $\Th(E_n \oplus M) \cong \Sigma^n \Th(M) \cong \Sigma^n \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2$, but this is absurd since $H^{n + 2}(\Sigma^n \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2$ and $H^*(S^1; \mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free. Thus, no such $\Phi$ exists and $E_n \oplus M$ is not orientable.
